# Find a monic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ whose Galois group is $V_4$

Tags: galois-theory

I need to find a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ whose Galois group is $V_4=\langle(12)(34),(13)(24)\rangle\subset S_4$. I can find examples of such polynomials, but I wonder if one can construct such a polynomial by hand.

Can anyone offer some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Take any Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ such that the Galois group is $V_4$. Pick an element $a$ such that $K=\mathbb{Q}(a)$. Find the minimal polynomial of $a$.

Answer (score 2):

What about $\,f(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)\in\Bbb Q[x]\,$ ? In fact, any other biquadratic of this form $\;(x^2-a)(x^2-b)\;$ works, when neither $\,a,b,ab\,$ is a square.

Comment: No. This polynomial is reducible, so its Galois group is not transitive. But $V_4$ is transitive. I think the Galois group of this polynomial is $C_2\times C_2$.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused: what do you call $\,V_4\,$ to? For me it is the non-cyclic group of order $\,4\,$ , namely $\,C_2\times C_2\;$ , also known as Klein Viergrup...

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clear, I mean $\langle(12)(34),(13)(24)\rangle\subset S_4$.

Comment: @Montez, that group **is** the very same group I meant! It is isomorphic with $\,C_2\times C_2\,$ ,as you can easily check!

Comment: BTW, non reducible pol. $\;\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\implies\;$ non-transitive Galois Group.

Answer (score 0):

Try $x^4 - 10x^2 +1$, which as a splitting field of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and Galois group isomorphic to $V_4$.